# New Wordpress posts generate 404 error

Tags: wordpress

I had a working installation of WordPress, and I recently encountered an issue where when I tried to login to the back-end, the browser would redirect to the login URL of the previous domain WordPress was installed on.

I fixed this by reinstalling WordPress, and I can now login to the backend, but any new posts I make, or old posts I have generate 404 errors.

Additionally, if I try to navigate to any category page, I again receive a 404 error.

I have looked at the wp_posts table of my database, and the GUID field each contains the correct domain name and URL structure.

What should I be checking here?

[Site in question](http://www.superlogical.net).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try resaving your permalink structure (even if they seem correct). Sometimes when you are messing with wordpress, the htaccess file gets out of wack. I've had a similar issue to what you are describing and resaving the permalinks fixed the problem.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: Found out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Check in the wp_options table for the option `siteurl` and make sure it contains the value of your new domain name.

Comment: siteurl is correctly set to the domain of my website.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to this answer:

Could be permissions issues with your .htaccess file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Clear every information on your MySQL database for wordpress and try reinstalling. It's possible the new database is conflicting with the old one.